# SQL Radius Searching in one table connected with another

Tags: php, mysql, database

Please can you tell me how to join two tables when i want to get all shops from table one based on specific city_id which has own geo_lat and geo_long in table two? I want to get all shops in radius 25 km from my shop.

Table one - shops:
shop_name, shop description, town_id

Table two - cities:
city_id, city_name, geo_lat, geo_long

I tried a lot of examples and methods to do but with no result.

I find out this code for the distance:

```
SELECT
  id, (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians( lat ) )
      * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( lat ) )
    )
  ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 30
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

I will be very thankful to each of your answers. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is town_id in table one same as city_id in table two?

Comment: Yes town_id in table one is equivalent to city_id in table two. Which means when i have a city with city_id: 1 and the city_name: prague in table two and then i have a shop in table 1 with town_id: 1 -> this city of my shop will be Prague.

Answer (score 0):

```
    select s.shop_name, s.shop_description, s.town_id, c.city_id, c.city_name, c.geo_lat, c.geo_long from shops s
    right join cities c on c.city_id = s.town_id 
and (
    3959 * acos (
      cos ( radians(78.3232) )
      * cos( radians(c.geo_lat ) )
      * cos( radians( c.geo_long ) - radians(65.3234) )
      + sin ( radians(78.3232) )
      * sin( radians( c.geo_lat ) )
    )
  ) <= 25
    where c.city_name = 'Prague'
```

Comment: But i want to get all of other shops from table one which are in 25km of radius from the town_id...

Comment: Post some of the records from both tables that will help in giving you a better answer. I thought you were just trying to figure out how to do a join.

Comment: Here is it: http://www.nixotrade.cz/city_table.jpg and http://www.nixotrade.cz/shops_table.jpg

Comment: I don't know if the calculation are correct or not, if they are correct this should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: here is the example of the calculation [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31628/find-points-within-a-distance-using-mysql) and numbers 78.32.32 and 65.3234 must be replaced... and one next thing is that i think that the where statement where c.city_name = 'Prague' could be also replaced be c.city_id = specific_ID_WHICH_I_AM_LOOKING_FOR... can you tell me how update a coords? thanks you a lot.